# Relaunch view when app is closed

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, statusbar

I am creating a status bar app for Mac with a settings view.

I have created a NSMenuItem to launch the settings but I don't find any solutions to launch this view.

What I have tried:

`NSWorkspace.shared().launchApplication("AppName")`

and

```
StatusMenuController.swift

func showSettings() {

    var mainWindow: MainWindowController!
    mainWindow = MainWindowController()
    mainWindow.showWindow(nil)
}

MainWindowController.swift

override func windowDidLoad() {
    super.windowDidLoad()

    self.window?.center()
    self.window?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
}
```

Comment: Is the settings view a standalone window or the view that will be displayed when the user clicks the system menu item?

Comment: @theeagle it is a view that I have in a storyboard that should be displayed when the user clicks the menu item

Answer (score 0):

I saw this problem was faced in many cases and I found a solution that I don't completely understand but that I'll try to explain.

Here is how documents are managed in macOS :

[image: Document architecture in macOS]

From my experience, you need to check the box **"Create Document-Based Application"** when creating a new Mac app to have a `NSDocument` class (You can also add it later) which will handle how your views are being showed or not.

Adding this NSDocument class to my project made the following code work (and wasn't before) :

```
let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
var windowController: NSWindowController!
windowController = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "ScanWindowController") as! NSWindowController
windowController.showWindow(nil)
```